# how following error can be resolved while importing data from sqoop to hive/hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

18/07/24 11:59:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
18/07/24 11:59:24 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local180815535_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class sqltable not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:551)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class sqltable not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2395)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:237)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.(MapTask.java:521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class sqltable not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2393)
        ... 12 more

Comment: Can you please post your Sqoop command

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqldb --username root --password pswd --table sqltable  --hive-import -m 1

Comment: I have also tried with sqoop import --bindir /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/ad8c85b6ae0c483b549825f8b3bf280c --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqldb --username root --password pswd --table sqltable  --hive-import